# cmake built a 32 bit project in my 64 bit windows

Tags: cmake, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I'm using a cmake file(someone else wrote it) to build a project. I looked at the CMakeLists and saw he used

> if( CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8 )

to detect if the system is 64 bit. I'm using 64 bit windows 8 and it should be built into a 64 bit project. Why do I end up having a 32 bit project? Is there any other thing I should do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you invoke CMake, specify `Win64` in the generator option.  e.g.:

```
cmake . -G"Visual Studio 11 Win64"
```

Comment: At the new cmake version it is not possible to specify win64 like this. I think it generates project files according to which command prompt it is run at, x64 or x86..

Comment: This is still valid as of the current version (2.8.12.1)

Comment: You can use the `CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME` variable to check the invoked generator platform, e.g. `x64` or `Win32`.